# Append a dictionary key to a list depending on the value of the key

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary, append

While iterating in a for loop, I am trying to append a dictionary item's key to a list if the item has a value of `1`.

What I have is:

```
peeps = {'scoobydoo':0, 'shaggy':0, 'scrappydoo':0, 'velma':1, 'freddy':0, 'daphne':1}
ignore_list = []
for peep in peeps:
    if peep == 1:
        ignore_list.append(peep)
print(ignore_list)
```

This however does not give me what I would expect:

```
['velma', 'daphne']
```

It prints an empty list:

```
[]
```

Comment: Thanks, I was about to use iteritems() but peeps[peep] is simple and works great, thanks Avinash and Martijn!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't check for the *value*, only for the key itself.

Check the value by accessing it:

```
for peep in peeps:
    if peeps[peep] == 1:
        ignore_list.append(peep)
```

or loop over both keys and values together:

```
for peep, peep_value in peeps.items():
    if peep_value == 1:
        ignore_list.append(peep)
```

You can build the list in one step using a list comprehension here:

```
ignore_list = [peep for peep, peep_value in peeps.items() if peep_value == 1]
```

Comment: I need to look into that list comprehension stuff.  It seems nice to accomplish something in one line.  Know any good tutorials?

Comment: @mdandr: you could just start with the [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

Answer (score 1):

You're iterating over keys not values. So you need to combine the key with the actual dictionary to check if the value of that corresponding key is equal to 1 or not.

```
peeps = {'scoobydoo':0, 'shaggy':0, 'scrappydoo':0, 'velma':1, 'freddy':0, 'daphne':1}
ignore_list = []
for peep in peeps:
    if peeps[peep] == 1:
        ignore_list.append(peep)
print(ignore_list)
```

OR

```
peeps = {'scoobydoo':0, 'shaggy':0, 'scrappydoo':0, 'velma':1, 'freddy':0, 'daphne':1}
print([key for key,value in peeps.items() if value == 1])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through the keys and values of the dictionary to accomplish what you want:

```
peeps = {'scoobydoo':0, 'shaggy':0, 'scrappydoo':0, 'velma':1, 'freddy':0, 'daphne':1}
ignore_list = []
for key, value in peeps.items():
    if value == 1:
        ignore_list.append(key)
print(ignore_list)
```